# Radio buttons in Angular2 Model Driven forms not working as expected

Tags: html, angular, typescript

If I create radio buttons in my model driven form, they work fine but they don't have the radio button selected reflected by the formControlName default value.  For example:

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="isPublic" name="isPublic" value="false" id="keepPrivate" ><label for="keepPrivate">Keep it Private</label>
<input type="radio" formControlName="isPublic" name="isPublic" value="true" id="makePublic" ><label for="makePublic">Make it Public</label>
{{form.value.isPublic}}
```

If I have this it works correctly, but I can see the value of `form.value.isPublic` is false (as output in the last line to confirm) and yet no radio button is selected by default.

I tried to correct this by adding `[checked]` to each to drive the default value.  This works for the page load, in that defaults are properly selected in the radio buttons.  It even works for ONE selection - in that I can select the other radio button, it will be selected, the first one will be unselected, and the `{{form.value.isPublic}}` will change from `false` to `true`.

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="isPublic" [checked]="!form.value.isPublic" name="isPublic" value="false" id="keepPrivate" ><label for="keepPrivate">Keep it Private</label>
<input type="radio" formControlName="isPublic" [checked]="form.value.isPublic" name="isPublic" value="true" id="makePublic" ><label for="makePublic">Make it Public</label>
{{form.value.isPublic}}
```

The problem comes when I select the first radio button again - on the first click the radio button selection state doesn't change at all, but the `{{form.value.isPublic}}` output changes back to false.  If I click it again, then the radio button selection state changes.  So it takes two clicks to switch it back to the default.  If I click the other one again after that, it changes as expected but switching back to the first one takes two clicks (one click updates the form value and the second click changes the selection state of the radio button).

What should I be doing in this situation to have the radio buttons function correctly and reflect the default value for the form?

Comment: ...I should mention that, yes, this is all inside: `<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="update(form.value, form.valid)">...</form>`  Also my form group isn't actually named `form` but I'm just making it vanilla for the post.

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with using values from the form object to drive other Angular2 directives (like `*ngIf`) I discovered that the behaviour is always a little strange.  For example, if I draw parts of the page using `*ngIf` based on the value of `form.value.isProfilePublic`, the `*ngIf` section would only change once even though I can see the value of that variable is changing.  It isn't important to the answer so I won't elaborate but bottom line is that using form values to dynamically drive things that can update the form value itself doesn't work as I'd expect (likely for a good reason).

...so now I'm using a different variable not related to the form to drive the default selection and it works fine.  So, the following works:

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="isProfilePublic" name="isProfilePublic" [checked]="!currentUser.isProfilePublic" value="false" id="keepPrivate" ><label for="keepPrivate">Keep it Private</label>
<input type="radio" formControlName="isProfilePublic" name="isProfilePublic" [checked]="currentUser.isProfilePublic" value="true" id="makePublic" ><label for="makePublic">Make it Public</label>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't explain needing two clicks, but this should work:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" formControlName="isPublic" value="true" id="isPublic" (change)="form.value.isPublic = true"/> Make it public
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" formControlName="isPublic" value="false" id="isPublic" (change)="form.value.isPublic = false"/> Keep it private
</label>
```

On my project we are generating the radio buttons dynamically based on the 'questions' example in the docs for [Angular 2 Dynamic Forms](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html#)

```
<label class="radio-inline" *ngFor="let opt of input.options">
    <input type="radio" [formControlName]="input.key" [value]="opt.value" [id]="input.key" (change)="input.value = opt.value">
    {{opt.label}}
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks - yours does work, but it doesn't select the default value (which is data driven, I can't just set it in html).  Also - I can remove the `(change)` bit and it functions exactly the same.  As soon as I add `[checked]` back (with or without `(change)` it goes back to having my problem.  

I guess to get past this I can just do an `*ngIf` on isProfilePublic and write out completely different radio button sets with the defaults set in the HTML, but that seems pretty sloppy.

Comment: Thanks for the update - I think the bottom line in your other answer sounds sensible to me.  That's effectively what I'm doing in the second snippet, hooking the change event to update `input.value` which is, like you say, not the parent `form.value` variable.