# How can I pull id and value from a selected radio button to pass into an @Output?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I've done this a few years ago with JQuery with static form elements, but now that I'm using Angular2 and Typescript 2 and have to consider the fact that it won't always be the same data and values populating the component I can't wrap my head around the degree of "abstractness" required to figure this out.

So far this is how everything is set up.

The data coming in from Firebase

```
{
    "page_area_business_image"      : {
        "expand"    : {
            "intro" : "some info...",

            "title" : "a title"
        },
        "rebrand"   : {....},
        "newbrand"  : {....},
        "questions" : {
            "question01"    : {
                "id"        : "an ID",
                "name"      : "a name",
                "question"  : "a question",
                "answers"   : [
                    "answer01"  : {
                        "answer"    : "some answer",
                        "id"        : "an ID"
                    },
                    "answer02"  : {
                        "answer"    : "another answer",
                        "id"        : "an ID"
                    },
                    "answer02"  : {
                        "answer"    : "another answer",
                        "id"        : "another ID"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "question02"    : {....},
            "question03"    : {....}
        }
    }
}
```

I pass this data down to a child component which has it's own child component which is the "multiple choice" component I made for the questions.  The template binds the incoming question like this

```
<fieldset [attr.id]="question?.id" class="card col-8 justify-content-center">

    <label class="ques-title">
        {{featureQuestion?.question}}
    </label>

    <div class="row answer-row-section justify-content-center">

        <div *ngFor="let answer of featureQuestion?.answers" class="col col-12 answer-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col justify-content-center">

                <input type="radio"
                    [attr.id]   = "answer.id"
                    [attr.name] = "name"
                    [attr.value]= "answer.answer"
                    hidden />

                <label [attr.for]="answer.id" class="col ques-ans-title" style="background-color: #4b73a0;">
                    {{answer.answer}}
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</fieldset>
```

This is what my component class looks like so far

```
export class MultipleChoiceRadioComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input('question')
    featureQuestion: any;

    @Output()
    answerO: string;
    // Will be used to send the result back up to parent where if statements will trigger other elements



    ngOnChanges(){

        // I plan to put whatever I come up with here so the value can update if it changes.
        //console.log(this.answerO);
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

I came across this
[How to set radio button checked in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059444/how-to-set-radio-button-checked-in-angular-2)
but it was more or less triggering a true or false result, which I plan to do in the parent component, the `multiple choice` component can't be that specific so I couldn't really figure out a way to translate that into what I need.

I came across this
[Radio buttons in Angular2 Model Driven forms not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702031/radio-buttons-in-angular2-model-driven-forms-not-working-as-expected)
which led me to this
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html#
though VERY informative and useful in other ways, it says nothing of radio buttons.  I'm guessing you would link it all up the same way, but I'm also guessing there's some unique twist to both dealing with radio buttons and pulling the id as the desired result from being selected.

This seems to be closest to what I need to do
http://www.talkingdotnet.com/bind-radiobutton-list-in-angular-2/.  Only thing is figuring out what I need to do personally with the way my data is set up in order to make the suitable classes, plus I already have my data loading to the component, so this means I'd have to break what I did and send it in another way, which I figured is a bit much when if it's already there it has to be some way I can simply collect and update the result without having to change everything over to that.

Most of everything else I found was stuff for Angular 1.5 or an alpha version of Angular 2 which went off into creating controllers and filters and using `#` instead of `let`and all sorts of good stuff that's deprecated or flat out doesn't apply to Angular 2.  I've seen several that just used plain ol `document.getElementById()` but with the dynamic nature of things I can't just do it like that.  Or can I? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

just a quick hazard:

I believe what you want to do is use the radio-group directive, probably in or above your ngFor like so:

```
<div radio-group [(ngModel)]="selectedAnswer" *ngFor="let answer of featureQuestion?.answers" class="col col-12 answer-row justify-content-center">
```

Note: you might even want to put these changes in an enclosing div. Note: NgModel is bound to a new variable. This is going to hold the value that you have set in

```
        <input type="radio"
            [attr.id]   = "answer.id"
            [attr.name] = "name"
            [attr.value]= "answer.answer"  <<<Here
            hidden />
```

I hope this helps

Also, I just realised, you'll probably want many radiogroups? In which case, instead bind the ngModel to an array of values

Comment: what is `radio-group`?  I googled it and didn't get anything back talking about it, I pretty much got the same websites I've been reading through all day about radio buttons.and what's `selectedAnswer`?  Is that a custom name you came up with or a feature of `radio-group`?

Comment: ok I just came across something pointing to react js, is that where it comes from?  Because I don't see anything else out there about angular 2 having a `radio-group`.